# Java Float Precision for values between 0 and 1

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

I have values between 0 and 1 stored as floats.
I know that delta between distinguishable floats is smaller the closer the floats are to 0. Thus, I think the precision is very high in my case (as the highest possible float is 1..). How big is my epsilon that I have to consider when comparing 2 of these floats? i.e. how big is the gap between 1.0f and the biggest representable float that is smaller than 1.0f? I am sorry if this question seems too broad/general but I could not find an answer :-(.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the function `java.lang.Math.nextAfter(float start, double direction)` to help you.

Call it using, in your case, `nextAfter(1.0f, 0.0)`. Here we're setting the `direction` to be less than your starting number, so it will search "backwards". The resulting `float` is your answer.

Because this function also has an overload taking a `double` for `start`, be careful to use `1.0f` to denote a `float` literal.

Comment: If using 1.8 or later, `java.lang.Math.nextDown(1.0f)` or, if using the usually better choice of `double` instead of `float`, `java.lang.Math.nextDown(1.0)`

Comment: I know double would be better, but I am running out of memory, so I want to figure out if float suffices for my purposes. Anyway, thanks for the comment, because use Java 1.8 and thus can use the respective function.

Answer (score 1):

To get the unit of resolution for a float or double value you can use `Math.ulp(x)` which will give you the difference between `x` and the next representable value. Note: `1` has double the gap of the value immediately before 1.0

```
float f = 1.0f, f_1 = Math.nextDown(f);
double d = 1.0, d_1 = Math.nextDown(d);

int f_1i = Float.floatToRawIntBits(f_1);
System.out.println("f_1=" + f_1 + " f_1i=" + Integer.toHexString(f_1i) + " eps=" + Math.ulp(f_1) + " nextUp=" + Math.nextUp(f_1));

int fi = Float.floatToRawIntBits(f);
System.out.println("f=" + f + " fi=" + Integer.toHexString(fi) + " eps=" + Math.ulp(f) + " nextUp=" + Math.nextUp(f));

long d_1i = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d_1);
System.out.println("d_1=" + d_1 + " d_1i=" + Long.toHexString(d_1i) + " eps=" + Math.ulp(d_1) + " nextUp=" + Math.nextUp(d_1));

long di = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d);
System.out.println("d=" + d + " di=" + Long.toHexString(di) + " eps=" + Math.ulp(d) + " nextUp=" + Math.nextUp(d));
```

prints

```
f_1=0.99999994 f_1i=3f7fffff eps=5.9604645E-8 nextUp=1.0
f=1.0 fi=3f800000 eps=1.1920929E-7 nextUp=1.0000001
d_1=0.9999999999999999 d_1i=3fefffffffffffff eps=1.1102230246251565E-16 nextUp=1.0
d=1.0 di=3ff0000000000000 eps=2.220446049250313E-16 nextUp=1.0000000000000002
```

You can also do arithmetic on the representable values by looking at the raw integer representations.

e.g. Math.nextUp

```
public static double nextUp(double d) {
    if( Double.isNaN(d) || d == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
        return d;
    else {
        d += 0.0d;
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) +
                                       ((d >= 0.0d)?+1L:-1L));
    }
}
```

BTW `d += 0.0d` turns `-0.0` into `+0.0`

Also

```
System.out.println(Math.ulp(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));
```

prints

```
Infinity
```

Comment: @Bathsheba hehe, you seem so surprised. ;)